# How can I include and call the BSImagePicker in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, image, swiftui, imagepicker

How can I include the BSImagePicker in this construct and save the images in an array?

```
import SwiftUI
import BSImagePicker

struct ContentView: View {
    ...
    var body: some View {
        ...
        Button(action: {
            //Here the Image Picker should be called                      
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "camera")
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no possiblity to make it select more than one item. You can continue your research here:
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=multiple+image+picker+swiftui&t=ffcm&ia=web
https://www.pawelmadej.com/post/multi-select-picker-for-swiftui/